# Function type to which a pointer to member refers

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

N3797::8.3.5/6

> A function type with a cv-qualifier-seq or a ref-qualifier (including
>   a type named by typedef-name (7.1.3, 14.1)) shall appear only as:
>
> [...]
>
> — the function type to which a pointer to member refers
>
> [...]

Could you get an example? I'm trying the following:

```
struct A
{
    int foo();
};

int A::* foo() &; //ill-formed.

struct B
{
    int (*bar)() &; //ill-formed
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to put it [through a compiler](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b79eaef7e68435af).

The former,

```
int A::* foo() &;
```

is incorrect syntax. To create a pointer to member function, you still need to put in the parenthesis:

```
int (A::*foo)() &;
```

and then it is accepted just fine.

The other,

```
int (*bar)() &;
```

is accepted by gcc, but my local `clang` rejects it with

> 13 col 10 error: pointer to function type cannot have '&' qualifier

and rightfully so. It is a pointer to non-member function and there is nothing to qualify as reference. Gcc apparently just ignores the `&` instead.